# Copy mymacro /source to another library?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Let's say I stored a macro the following way :

```
options mstored sasmstore=FOO;
%macro hello_world() / STORE SOURCE DES='hello world';
  %put hello world;
%mend;
```

Now I want to copy this macro from library `FOO` to library `BAR`, I would like something like (this obviously doesn't work):

```
%copy hello_world /source LIB = BAR;
```

This would be the equivalent of doing :

```
options mstored sasmstore=BAR;
%macro hello_world() / STORE SOURCE DES='hello world';
  %put hello world;
%mend;
```

The goal is to conveniently copy macros from a development library to a production library. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proc CATALOG` is used to copy entries from one member to another

```
%macro One;
%put ONE;
%mend;

proc catalog catalog=work.sasmacr;
  copy out=work.holdmacr;
  select one / et=macro;
run;
```

An alternative to copying entries is to use the concatenation feature that is provided automatically with `LIBNAME`.

From SAS Help

> #### Example 3: Concatenating SAS Catalogs
>
> This example concatenates three SAS libraries by specifying the
>   physical filename of each and assigns the libref ALLMINE to the
>   concatenated libraries:
>
> `libname allmine ('file-1' 'file-2' 'file-3');`
>
> If each library contains a SAS catalog named MYCAT, then using
>   ALLMINE.MYCAT as a libref.catref provides access to the catalog entries
>   that are stored in all three catalogs named MYCAT. To logically
>   concatenate SAS catalogs with different names, see the CATNAME
>   Statement.

*If the same name catalogs contain same named entries, the entry in the earliest library is used.*

This is really handy during unit tests as the original does not have to be altered until updates are proven to be non-damaging.  You have integration unit tests right ? ;-)

Comment: Thanks to both of you, there aren't many answerers on the `sas` tag but I'm amazed that the answers are usually quick and the quality is always top notch. Ah... unit tests... I have some, not to the standard I would be comfortable with but these things take time and are already far out of my job description :).

Comment: can you tell me more about `holdmacr` vs `sasmacr` ? @Joe only mentions `sasmacr`

Comment: `holdmacr` is just a target catalog for the purpose of demonstrating how to copy a macro entry from one catalog to another.  `holdmacr` has no operative role in the SAS session.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move the macro to production, `PROC CATALOG` is the correct way to do it.

```
*define foo;
libname foo "c:\temp";

*create the stored macro;
options mstored sasmstore=FOO;
%macro hello_world() / STORE SOURCE DES='hello world';
  %put hello world;
%mend;

*define bar;
libname bar "c:\otherdir";

*proc catalog to copy it over;
PROC Catalog catalog = foo.sasmacr;
             copy out=bar.sasmacr;
run;

***reset SAS session before continuing to clear libname foo***;


*now redirect SAS to BAR;
libname bar "c:\otherdir";
options mstored sasmstore=bar;

*and run hello_World- see it works!;
%hello_world;
```

Now, I probably wouldn't do it this way - I'd use git to store and deploy the source files - but if you prefer stored compiled macros, this is the best way.

Comment: Many thanks Joe great answer as usual, I had to mix it with @Richard's answer as he mentions the `select ... / et=macro;` bit and you didn't. I appreciate the tip on workflow too, it would be time consuming to teach `git` to my team though so I took a more straightforward route.

Comment: git is very easy to learn..  and is a far better approach than dealing with catalogs!